# HTMLElement passed to DivIcon in Leaflet doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

I want to pass an `HTMLElemnt` object to a [`DivIcon`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#divicon) in [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com) in an Angular app.

This is my `img` element in text:

```
<img src="assets/images/icons/marker.png" style="width:100%;height:100%;" />
```

When I pass the above string to the `DivIcon.html` property, it works fine, the image is displayed.

But now, I'm trying to pass an `HTMLElement` (which the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#divicon) says it supports)

```js
this.markerElement = document.createElement('img');
this.markerElement.src = 'assets/images/icons/marker.png';
this.markerElement.style.width = '100%';
this.markerElement.style.height = '100%';

this.markerIcon = new DivIcon({
  iconSize: [40, 40],
  iconAnchor: [20, 20],
  html: this.markerElement,
  className: 'marker-position-icon'
});
```

I even tried using the angular `Renderer2`:

```js
constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
  this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
}

init () {
    this.markerElement = this.renderer.createElement('img');
    ...
```

It still doesn't work. Is it a problem because it's an `HTMLImageElement`? (I guess not)

This is how it gets displayed:

(without the red box)

[image]

Comment: It's a relativly new option https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/6571/files are you using the latest version? I would probably just use `html: this.markerElement.outerHTML`

Comment: I used the `outerHTML` property and now it works! But my typescript lint still suggests that I can pass an `HTMLElement` to the `html` property. Not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Then the question is what version of Leaflet you're using.

Comment: ping... Which version?—I mean... we know that outerHTML works, because it is a string again!